# How to set permission on document level during the upload in share point online

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation

we are using O365 sharepoint online.

The question: once we upload a document to a specific document library, how can we set permissions on document level based on a dropdown list? (e.g. when I upload a file, I want to have access to it -owner- and I would like to give X_AD_Group access to that document.

regards,

Answer (score 0):

You can use Workflow to achieve that.

Steps:

1. Allowing a workflow to use app permissions in a SharePoint Server online site.

   - Go to Site settings > Manage site features > Active "Workflows can use app permissions".
   - Go to Site settings > Site app permissions > Copy the client section of the  App Identifier. The client section is in between "|" and "@".
   - Grant permission to the app by going to `https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/<site>/_layouts/15/appinv.aspx`. Paste the client id in the App Id field, and click Lookup. Then the following Permissions Request XML to grant full control permission.

   - Click Create, then click Trust It.

For more details, you should refer to: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj822159.aspx

2. Create a workflow with SharePoint 2010 Workflow platform type for the document library.

[image]

3. Add an Impersonation Step.
4. Use “Wait for Field Change in Current Item” to wait for the “People and Group” field has value. In my test, the “People and Group” field is named “ToUsers”.
5. Insert a “Replace List Item Permissions” Action to allow only specific users have access on the current item.

[image]

6. Start this workflow when an item is created.
   [image]
7. Publish the workflow.

After that, when user uploads an file and enters the “ToUsers” People and Group field, the workflow will be triggered. The file will have unique permissions, and only owner (Created By) and “ToUsers” have permissions to it.

Comment: beautiful 2010 workfows with app steps , why are 2013 workflows so lame ?

Comment: With 2013 workflow, we need to use Rest Api. Refer to http://www.benprins.net/2017/01/03/sharepoint-2013-workflow-changing-permissions-with-rest-calls/ They are different. If you think my answer is helpful, please "accept" this answer.